# In Python Pandas Can't add new column after datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, concatenation

I cannot concatenate new columns to existing Pandas DataFrame if the last column of the existing DataFrame is in the type of datetime. Here is a minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates      = [pd.Timestamp('2012-05-01'), pd.Timestamp('2012-05-02'), 
             pd.Timestamp('2012-05-03')]
ed         = pd.DataFrame( dates, index = range(3), columns=['Time'])
ed['Time'] = ed['Time'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('US/Central')

ed         = pd.concat([ed, pd.DataFrame(columns = [ 'Column1', 'Column2'] 
             )], sort = False)



Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2878, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-2-c82182e48b5f>", line 8, in <module>
ed         = pd.concat([ed, pd.DataFrame(columns = [ 'Column1', 'Column2'] )], sort = False)
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 226, in concat
return op.get_result()
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 423, in get_result
copy=self.copy)
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 5421, in concatenate_block_managers
concatenate_join_units(join_units, concat_axis, copy=copy),
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 5565, in concatenate_join_units
for ju in join_units]
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 5851, in get_reindexed_values
 if not self.block._can_consolidate:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_can_consolidate'
```

Comment: can you shortly include your traceback/exceptions

Comment: @sudonym I just included the traceback information.

Answer (score 0):

what if you change the `ed['Time']` column after concating `ed` to the new df?

```
dates = [pd.Timestamp('2012-05-01'), pd.Timestamp('2012-05-02'), pd.Timestamp('2012-05-03')]
ed = pd.DataFrame( dates, index = range(3), columns=['Time'])
ed['Time'] = ed['Time'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('US/Central')
ed = pd.concat([ed, pd.DataFrame(columns = [ 'Column1', 'Column2'])], sort = False, axis=1)
```

Comment: That's how I did it right now to avoid the error. I don't why I cannot do this another way?

Comment: it looks like all was needed is passing `axis=1`  to concatenate df's column-wise. i updated the answer.